# Building MariaDB with musl: /usr/bin/ld cannot find -lgcc_s

Tags: gcc, makefile, cmake, mariadb, musl

I am trying to [build MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/building-mariadb-from-source-using-musl-based-gnulinux/) v10.3 with a [musl](https://musl.libc.org/) tool chain on x86_64 Debian kernel v4.19. I have mainly been using the `musl-gcc` `gcc` wrapper to achieve this. The relevant packages I installed are as follows:

- `musl` (1.1.21-2): standard C library
- `musl-dev` (1.1.21-2): standard C library development files
- `musl-tools` (1.1.21-2): standard C library tools

To build MariaDB, I first run:

```
CC=/usr/bin/musl-gcc cmake ../ -DWITHOUT_TOKUDB=1
```

which exits cleanly, and then I follow that up with:

```
make CC=/usr/bin/musl-gcc
```

which error with the following message:

```
Scanning dependencies of target strings-t
[ 12%] Building C object unittest/strings/CMakeFiles/strings-t.dir/strings-t.c.o
[ 12%] Linking CXX executable strings-t
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [unittest/strings/CMakeFiles/strings-t.dir/build.make:94: unittest/strings/strings-t] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:731: unittest/strings/CMakeFiles/strings-t.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

Now I know the library that musl is looking for (`libgcc_s.so`) is located in `/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/` but my attempts to include the library using `LDFLAGS` or symlinking the library into `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl/` have failed.

Am I going about compiling MariaDB the right way? I imagine I am doing something wrong as Alpine Linux can run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will update this answer when I become completely successful, but the solution thus far has been to use [musl-cross-make](https://github.com/richfelker/musl-cross-make) to compile all libraries and such to specifically target musl. Since getting musl-cross-make I have been building all the dependencies from scratch (which is not fun :)). Thus far, I have gotten a more-or-less successful configuration and I am working on compilation (hammering out the last few dependencies).

I am using the following script to build things:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -euo pipefail

# musl paths
MUSL_PREFIX='/usr/local/x86_64-linux-musl'
MUSL_INC="$MUSL_PREFIX/include"
MUSL_LIB="$MUSL_PREFIX/lib"
CC='/usr/local/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-gcc'
CXX='/usr/local/bin/x86_64-linux-musl-g++'

    #
    # CMake couldn't locate lz4 when I installed it manually, so we bundle
    # it in with the MariaDB build
    #
    wget https://github.com/lz4/lz4/archive/v1.7.5.tar.gz
    tar -xzf v1.7.5.tar.gz
    rm v1.7.5.tar.gz
    mv lz4-1.7.5 /home/ajg/mariadb/storage/mroonga/vendor/groonga/vendor/

    # Configure the build
    CC="$CC"                        \
    CXX="$CXX"                      \
    LDFLAGS="-L$MUSL_LIB -Wl,-rpath,$MUSL_LIB"      \
    CFLAGS="-I$MUSL_INC"                    \
    CXXFLAGS="-I$MUSL_INC"                  \
    CPPFLAGS="-I$MUSL_INC"                  \
    CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="$MUSL_PREFIX"            \
    cmake . -DWITHOUT_TOKUDB=1 -DGRN_WITH_BUNDLED_LZ4=ON

    # Make it
    make                            \
    CC="$CC"                        \
    CXX="$CXX"                      \
    LDFLAGS="-L$MUSL_LIB -Wl,-rpath,$MUSL_LIB"      \
    CFLAGS="-I$MUSL_INC"                    \
    CXXFLAGS="-I$MUSL_INC"                  \
    CPPFLAGS="-I$MUSL_INC"
```

I hope this helps someone else out in the future :)

Comment: I guess this worked, but the build finally failed.. and it seemed to be looking for includes in the wrong directory.. (I was using cmake --build instead of make)

Answer (score 1):

Thus why don't looking how alpine is building it ?

https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/main/mariadb/APKBUILD?id=3ca8e70b047f37a01df42e3244014a6635893abc

seems they disable test
`-DSKIP_TESTS=ON`
ref: https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/main/mariadb/APKBUILD?id=3ca8e70b047f37a01df42e3244014a6635893abc#n186

And their ppc-glibc patch ?
https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/main/mariadb/ppc-remove-glibc-dep.patch?id=3ca8e70b047f37a01df42e3244014a6635893abc

Comment: Hi @Mizux thank you for your answer. While it didn't help me 100% it did contribute to solving some side problems I had. I actually ended up building `musl-cross-make` which solved the problem I had above...though I did end up running into another one.