# How does musl's GCC wrapper differ from musl's cross-compiler?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, glibc, musl

I am trying to compile various programs such as MariaDB with a [musl](https://musl.libc.org/) toolchain. That is, I don't want any dependencies on glibc or GNU's linker after compilation has finished.

Thus far, I have been using musl's GCC wrapper, `musl-gcc` to compile things. But, with larger programs like MariaDB I struggle to get all the necessary libraries and headers and symlinking or adding environment variables for the compilation [doesn't really help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64217764/building-mariadb-with-musl-usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-lgcc-s).

I see mention of [building a cross-compiler targeting musl libc](https://wiki.musl-libc.org/getting-started.html) with additional documentation and code at [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/richfelker/musl-cross-make). From the documentation on the cross-compiler:

> This gives you a full, relocatable musl-targeting toolchain, with C++ support and its own library paths you can install third-party libraries into.

It sounds like this could help me, but I am not sure how this is very different from musl's GCC wrapper, which as I understand, just alters where GCC looks for libraries and headers etc.

Ultimately, I am unsure how different this cross-compiler really is from the GCC wrapper and if it would be useful in my case. Why would I need my own library paths to install third-party libraries into when I can just symlink to existing libraries and use the GCC wrapper? Is the cross-compiler the way I should be compiling things, especially bigger code bases?

Comment: nowadays just compile in `docker run alpine`

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, that is an option. However, I am trying to run some benchmarks of musl vs. glibc -compiled programs and all glibc compilations were done on Debian. So for consistency I would like to keep things on Debian.

Comment: @peachykeen -- But does it matter what Linux distribution you use, since you're expressly removing platform-level dependencies? If you build for MUSL on an Alpine VM, and for glibc on a Debian VM, and both VMs run on the same host, doesn't that provide  a level playing field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All the wrapper does is remove the default library and include paths and add replacement ones. Otherwise, it relies on the *compiler's view of* the ABI being sufficiently matched that a GCC that thinks it's targeting glibc (`*-linux-gnu`) works with a musl (`*-linux-musl`) target.

A full GCC toolchain has a number of "target libraries" - libraries that are linked into the output program to provide some functionality the compiler offers. This includes `libgcc` (software multiply or divide, software floating point, etc. according to whether the target arch needs these things, and unwinding support for exception handling), `libstd++` (the C++ standard library), and a number of other things like `libgomp` (GNU OpenMP runtime implementation for use with `#pragma OMP ...`). In theory all of these possibly depend on the *specific* target ABI, including the libc, and potentially link to symbols from libc. In practice, for the most part `libgcc` doesn't, and is "safely" reusable with a different libc as long as the basic type definitions and a few other ABI things match.

For the other libraries with more complex dependencies on libc, it's generally not expected that a build against one libc would work with a different one. musl libc provides some degree of ABI-compat for using glibc-linked libraries, so there's some hope that they'd work anyway, but you'd need to copy them to the new library path. However, GCC's C++ standard library headers also seem to have some heavy dependency on the (libc) system headers for the target, and when setup for glibc do not seem to work with musl. There is probably some way to make this work (i.e. to add C++ support to the wrapper), but it's an open problem exactly how to do it.

Even if this could be made to work, though, the deeper you go, the more reasons you're likely to find that you'd rather just have a proper cross-compiler toolchain that *knows* it's targeting musl. And nowadays these are easy enough to build. But if you find you're needing additonal third party libraries too, and don't want to build them yourself, it probably makes more sense to just use a Docker image (or other container) with a distro that provides library binaries for you.